# Determine the cdf of $U = XY$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normally distributed random variables.

Tags: probability

I know they are both independent but shouldn't we have the joint pdf at least to get the cdf of $U = XY$?

Comment: We know the joint pdf, it is $\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

The pdf of the product of 2 independent standard Normal random variables, say $g(x)$, can be automatically derived with:

[image]

where I am using the `TransformProduct` function from the *mathStatica* package to perform the nitty-gritties.

Here is a plot of the pdf $g(x)$:

[image]

You seek the cdf i.e. $P_g(X \leq x)$:

[image]

Here is a plot of the cdf:

[image]

All done.

**Notes**

1. `TransformProduct` and `Prob` are functions from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.
2. `BesselK[n,z]` is the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_n(z)$
3. `StruveL[n,z]` gives the modified Struve function. For more detail, see  [StruveL](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StruveL.html)